# How can I convert onnx format to ptl format?

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, pytorch-lightning

Here I already got my `.onnx` format file: `retinaface.onnx`, I want to convert it to PyTorch mobile supported format: `.ptl` or `.pt`, then I can do inference in Android platform. But I failed to convert or to find relevant issues.

```py
// I want to load directly but failed
mRetinafaceDector =  LiteModuleLoader.load(mModelPath + "/retinaface.onnx");
```

Seems the `LiteModuleLoader.load()` can only load `.ptl` or `.pt`, but in my hand I only have `retinaface.onnx` format..

Answer (score 1):

You can't load onnx model directly to pytorch as it's not supported yet.

Fortunately you can use `onnx2pytorch` tool to convert onnx to pytorch

Firstly install it:
https://github.com/ToriML/onnx2pytorch

Then you can easily convert it using this code:

```
onnx_model = onnx.load(path_to_onnx_model)
pytorch_model = ConvertModel(onnx_model)
```

nevertheless, check this issue, it's about importing onnx directly in pytorch:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/21683

Comment: but then, pytorch_model has type ConvertModel. How to make an actual .pt-file of it?

Answer (score 1):

To convert ONNX to Torch, you can use `onnx2torch` instead of `onnx2pytorch`.

The github repo of `onnx2torch` is here: https://github.com/ENOT-AutoDL/onnx2torch

First install `onnx2torch`

```
pip install onnx2torch onnx
```

Then you can easily convert it using this code:

```
from onnx2torch import convert
path = '/path/to/your_model.onnx'
pytorch_model = convert(path)
```

As of 1/5/2023, I continue to observe the drawbacks of using this library for conversion, which include the fact that the model is not yet fully written in Torch. For instance:

```
GraphModule(
  (initializers): Module()
  (Sub_0): OnnxBinaryMathOperation()
  (Mul_0): OnnxBinaryMathOperation()
  (Transpose_0): OnnxTranspose()
  (Conv_0): Conv2d(3, 128, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(4, 4))
  (Transpose_1): OnnxTranspose()
  (Reshape_0): OnnxReshape()
  (ReduceMean_0): OnnxReduceStaticAxes()
  (Sub_1): OnnxBinaryMathOperation()
  (ReduceSumSquare_0): OnnxReduceStaticAxes()
  (Squeeze_0): OnnxSqueezeDynamicAxes()
  (Div_0): OnnxBinaryMathOperation()
  (BatchNormalization_0): OnnxBatchNorm()
  (Reshape_1): OnnxReshape()
...
  (Mul_257): OnnxBinaryMathOperation()
  (Add_220): OnnxBinaryMathOperation()
  (Gemm_0): Linear(in_features=9083, out_features=1024, bias=True)
  (Sigmoid_0): Sigmoid()
)
```

Comment: For anyone wandering you can then save your model with torch.save(pytorch_model, "pt_model_path")